# How can I check the size of input (in bytes) for a mapper?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I noticed among 500 mappers there are almost 3x completion time difference.

When I checked the logs (thru JobTracker web interface), I found that the difference is mainly in the 1st spill timing ("Finished spill 0").

This seems to imply that the input file size difference per mapper isn't really a factor. Probably a performance difference between different nodes? Any insight/comment would be welcome!

Comment: Can you provide some more information between the faster and slower running map tasks (map input records, map output records, data & rack locality?)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your mappers are doing to investigate the difference. You will have to investigate based on map job functions and what I/O and processing are involved.

There are three issues that can cause different performance difference in mappers.

1. File I/O which is localized but node dependent. Different node types can show different performance characteristics.
2. Network I/O : if your mappers are fetching data from elsewhere (Example: Sqoop Jobs that fetch data from database), then this is more significant issue and usually varies as mappers are executed at different time with different network characteristics.
3. Computing intensive jobs (Mapper performance): Should usually affect all the mappers similarly but is still node dependent.

Also if you are executing your job from command line, you should see the output similar to this (for network I/O)

```
mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=2958530
mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=87
mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=58294
mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=248301
mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=1679
mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=267583488
mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=2580
mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=158334976
mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=927236096
mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=1679
mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=87
mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 242.4814 KB in 2,964.2976 seconds (83.7639 bytes/sec)
mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1679 records.
```

You can see from that data processed and written to the file as well as transfer time.

[Edit:]

There are benchmark available that can help you check out Hadoop cluster characteristics:

1. TestDFSIO
2. MRBench

Comment: Thanks. For my case, it is more like case 1. I am looking at the machine specs and so on.

Comment: @Kee: Test first by writing to and from HDFS to local file system. Benchmark it. After that try first the MRBench to get a picture on how much time it takes to create and run no-operation map-reducer.

Comment: I see. One more question is that I don't see "mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred ..." output in my console. Is there some other flag I need to use in my command line?

Comment: @Kee; Thats ok! Thats a part of my map/reduce (Comes from Sqoop). It shows Network I/O data which you should not worry about. I suggest benchmarking your cluster.